# File upload blocked - error code 0x800700de "The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, file-upload

A user has encountered a curious issue when trying to upload a 3MB Excel file.  There are already other files greater than 3MB is size, so that's not the issue.

The error code is as you see in the picture below, "Error 0x800700DE: The file type being saved or retrieved has been blocked".  I found this error code on the [SCCM Error Code Bible on page 39](https://thewintelpro.co.uk/sccm-error-code-bible/).

[image: Error 0x800700DE]

- I'd be surprised if we'd put in place some kind of file blocking setting.
- This is an Excel file in .xlsx format, it is not a macro.
- Other Excel files have been uploaded already.
- Perhaps there is something else within the file that Sharepoint wants to block?  There is one link to another file on a file server contained in the file (I see this in Data/Connections/Edit Links in the Excel ribbon menu).

### File Permissions (in Excel itself)

[image: Excel Permissions]

The file does have password protected worksheets - can this be a reason for upload being blocked?  If so, where can I access these settings (I'm SP Admin)?

### SP User Permissions

- The user has contribute permissions and has uploaded other files today.
- I'm the SP Admin and I also can not upload the file.

### Other Links / Research

Suggested invalid characters in file name: [see link here](https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/upload-errors-to-sharepoint-error-code-0x800700de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of SharePoint you using now? First just have a check on the blocked file types in the Central Admin for all web applications.

1. Navigate to Central Administration.
2. Click on Security and navigate to General Security > Define blocked
   file types. Navigate to Web Application menu and choose Change Web
   Application. Now go to Select Web Application page.

If you see that a certain file type is blocked, you can unblock it simply by selecting it from the list and pressing the Delete key. After doing that, click OK to save changes.

Have a try to change the file name or use another browser.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for posting this.  Other users might benefit from this if they have a genuine blocked file type.  Plus your final tip was correct!

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh.... it was just an invalid character in the file name.  Sharepoint doesn't like things like this chappie:  &

Or a host of other 'shady characters', although it seems to depend on which version of Sharepoint you are using - [check here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#invalidcharacters).

For me on 2013 there is a longer list of invalids: ~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }.

For SP Online: " * : < > ? / \ |

Comment: I had similar case where file had additional dot at extension, eg. file..pdf file [dot][dot] pdf. Removing one dot fixed error.